# Overlay video with moving images FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a video and few images. I know two places in the video where I want to paste these images. But they shouldn't have fixed position and size. On the contrary, images should move, change their tilt angle and scale. For example you may imagine closed book and you want to overlay its name when the book is slowly opens.
I read FFMPEG documentation but didn't found anything about this. Can FFMPEG do this? If not, which libraries or methodics can do that?

Comment: FFmpeg is not a compositor or motion tracker.

Answer (score 0):

The FFMPEG overlay filter can overlay one stream atop another.
It takes an expression which is evaluated per frame to determine the position.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1

You may consider creating a filter chain to do the following.

1) Create a transparent image with the title of your book.
2) Use a 3D rotate filter to convert the single image into an animated sequence
3) Use the overlay filter to apply the animated stream atop your book video.

Comment: This is a very broad answer. Generally we try to provide more detailed, specific answers. For example, how do you do steps 1, 2, and 3? You didn't provide any details.

Comment: Steps 1 and 3 are clear - create image and export final video. For step 2 if I get you right, I have to create rotate-scale-effect fot this image for each shot.